# Apache2 ignores ServerAlias

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, namevirtualhost, serveralias

the www versions of all my sites work. the non-www version don't work. All non-www versions go to my default vhost (galengrover.com)

Here are the first 2 virtual hosts in httpd.conf.

```
ServerName galengrover.com

NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin galenjr@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/galengrover.com/html
    ServerName www.galengrover.com
    ServerAlias galengrover.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin galenjr@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/skatevideosonline.net/html
    ServerName www.skatevideosonline.net
    ServerAlias skatevideosonline.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Im clueless. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Has DNS propigated? For me, `galengrover.com` 301 redirects to `www.galengrover.com`.

`skatevideosonline.com` is a [spam blog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_blog). `skatevideosonline.net` shows content from `www.galengrover.com` but `skatevideosonline.net` isn't a ServerAlias in the configuration you posted...

Did you mean

```
ServerName www.skatevideosonline.net
ServerAlias skatevideosonline.net
```

instead of

```
ServerName www.skatevideosonline.net
ServerAlias skatevideosonline.com
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `ServerName` directive outside of your `<VirtualHost>` blocks.